# Google Picker docsUploadView()

Tags: google-drive-api, google-picker

I am using DocsUploadView() in Google Picker to upload documents to the Google Drive. However, I want to add content to the 'description' and 'indexableText' fields at the time of upload. What would be a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The Picker API doesn't support editing file metadata during the upload process, but you can use the Drive API to update the document after it is uploaded:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v1/reference/files/update

The Picker will provide you with the id of the document at the end of the upload and that is the only required parameter for the API call.